# How to establish VPN Connection using Vodafone K3773 HSPA USB Stick?

Tags: networking, vpn, pptpd

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop. I am trying to establish VPN PPTP connection to Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

VPN connection available when PC is connected to LAN -> ADSL modem -> Internet -> VPN Server.

No VPN connection available when using 3G modem Vodafone K3773 HSPA USB Stick -> Internet -> VPN Server.

Internet is connected. VPN is not. How to establish the VPN Connection?

Server side log: `GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was NAT. I used OpenVPN instead PPTP.

In case of using "3G modem Vodafone K3773 HSPA USB Stick" connection goes through the Vodafone firewall. It may be an incompatibility with Vodafone firewall. I used OpenVPN package to create vpn-network instead pptpd. It is working fine.

Comment: Could you expand the answer explaining how did you troubleshoot, so that if someone else faces the situation they would be able to help themselves?